# Do not resume MPMoviePlayerController when application enters foreground

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking, resume

I am developing an iPhone application which plays the video using `MPMoviePlayerController`. When I switch to background(device with multi-tasking support), the video play is paused and when I bring my app to foreground video play is resumed.

But, when I switch to foreground I do not want my video to be resumed. I tried to pause the `MPMoviePlayerController` in the method applicationWillEnterForeground. But, I think they resume implicitely after call to `applicationWillEnterForeground`. Is there any notification methods that corresponds to   `applicationDidEnterForeground` OR `applicationWillEnterBackground`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although as you know `UIApplicationDidEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterBackgroundNotification` do not exist, there are functions that correspond to the same thing.

They are,

`UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`:

and

`UIApplicationWillResignActive`:

Comment: The documentation mentions that app will lose focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked. Can you please give me an example for the scenario 'app loses focus when overlay window pops up' .

Comment: When an external device function assumes control of the view, if the user receives a phone call for example, just before switching the view to the phone call, the method:

Comment: When an external device function assumes control of the view, if the user receives a phone call for example, just before switching the view to the phone call, the method **- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application** within your *AppName*AppDelegate.m is called. Once the view has been switched to the phone call (or any other controlling view) **- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application** is then called from your *AppName*AppDelegate.m file to do additional tasks in the background.

Comment: Once the device switches back to your application, it calls **- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application** followed by **- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application**, both again contained in *AppName*AppDelegate.m

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, the method that you are looking for, *applicationDidEnterForeground*, does exist; however, it is defined as **applicationDidBecomeActive**

Comment: Thanks. My doubts regarding usage of applicationDidBecomeActive is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the UIApplication Class Reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728

In the notifications section of that document, you'll find the notifications posted to the Notification center. Your class can register to receive these notifications and handle the video playback state appropriately.

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: If you are talking about 'UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification' and 'UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification', it will not help me. I wanted notification of kind UIApplicationDidEnterForegroundNotification and UIApplicationWillEnterBackgroundNotification