# MPMoviePlayerViewController dismissed when putting app in background

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play a video as modal view controller, but noticed that on application pause (home button pressed), it is dismissed automatically (a few seconds after the home button was pressed, *before* app is resumed) and my previous view controller is shown. From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6703544/245706), it seems that actually it should pause/resume correctly instead of dismissing. What could be the reason it's behaving differently for me (iOS 6.1.3, iPhone 4)?

Answer (score 1):

You may have been using ARC and declared the MPMoviePlayerController object in .m file.Declare the object and property in .h file as retain,nonatomic.And synthesize the object.